# Why is the --output option ignored in node-sass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, npm-scripts, node-sass

I tried to compile SASS using npm scripts with the following directory configuration.

```
project
├ page1
│ └ style
│ 　 ├ sass
│ 　 │ └ *.scss
│ 　 └ css
├ page2
│ └ style
│ 　 ├ sass
│ 　 │ └ *.scss
│ 　 └ css
├ ...
├ pageN
│ └ style
│ 　 ├ sass
│ 　 │ └ *.scss
│ 　 └ css
└ package.json
```

So I thought about using the `--output` option of glob and node-sass.

```
{
  "name": "sass",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "sass": "node-sass ./**/style/sass/ --output ./**/style/css/"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0"
  }
}
```

But this did not generate a CSS file in the CSS directory.

Instead, there is a CSS file in the SASS directory. This means that the `--output` option to specify the output directory is ignored.

How do I compile these into a css directory using npm script?

```
$ npm run sass

> sass@1.0.0 sass C:\Users\sanriot\Desktop\project
> node-sass ./**/assets/sass/ --output ./**/assets/css/

Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to C:\Users\sanriot\Desktop\project\page1\style\sass\style.css
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to C:\Users\sanriot\Desktop\project\page2\style\sass\style.css
Rendering Complete, saving .css file...
Wrote CSS to C:\Users\sanriot\Desktop\project\page3\style\sass\style.css
Wrote 3 CSS files to C:\Users\sanriot\Desktop\project\**\style\css\
```

Answer (score 0):

Options need to go before the input https://github.com/sass/node-sass#usage-1 `node-sass [options] <input> [output]`.